# create a table for each country that is needed - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database with an structure like this:

- t_person(idp, idcity, name, addr, tels, zip, desc, premium)
- t_city(idcity, idcountry, cityname)
- t_country(idcountry, countryname)

I want a very general "live search" (google-like):

```
SELECT p.name, p.addr, p.zip, p.desc, c.cityname, x.countryname, 
MATCH (p.name, p.addr, p.zip, p.desc) 
AGAINST ('fred* tall* 94620*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM t_person p
INNER JOIN t_city c ON c.idcity = p.idcity
INNER JOIN t_country x ON x.idcountry = c. idcountry 
WHERE MATCH (p.name, p.addr, p.zip, p.desc) 
AGAINST ('fred* tall* 94620*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND x.idcountry = 43 -- (i.e USA)
ORDER BY score DESC, p.name ASC, p.premium DESC
```

When there are only 1000 - 1500 rows, this query runs in about 0.011 secs but when there are 30000+ rows It will take about 1.2+ seconds (I have tested it with a data generator).
The question is, what if I create a new table for evey country(1 --- n) person, something like this:
t_person_uk, t_person_usa, t_person_spain, each with 1500 rows, I think this way the searches will be very fast.
PD, I already have a 0.25 second timeout before make the AJAX call to search.

thanks, good bye.

Comment: Don't create tables for each country unless indexing has failed you.  Where have you defined indexes? What does your EXPLAIN tell you?

Comment: Full text index(p.nombre, p.addr, p.zip, p.desc, p.tels) /
And the EXPLAIN says everything is ok,  rows 1, 1, 1, 32000(the generated data I used for testing) PRIMARY KEY everywhere, Keylength 2, null, 3, 2, Also: the pagination (LIMIT 0, 15) won`t work because I have to order by best match, name ASC, "premium" DESC (some users are "premium") and you know how mysql works (it is the same or worst that selecting all the rows at the same time). - without limit = 1.189 Secs, With LIMIT 0, 15 = 1.219 secs

Comment: what is x.idpais?  I don't see it anywhere in your schema.

Comment: x.idpais = x.idcountry sorry (span_glish)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question at all, but a bit too long for a comment.

In general, these types of searches are built with full-text indexing search engines rather than MySQL. A full-text search engine will offer you many more possibilities than the standard `MATCH` from MySQL.

For example, you will be able to do partial matches, return distance-sorted results, auto-suggest and auto-completes. MySQL will only provide you with the bare minimum: one matching function with two or three modes.

A good example of full-text indexing is [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/), built on top of Lucene.

Also, a free and very comprehensive database of geographic data is available at [geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt).

Hopefully this is not too off-topic for you :)

Comment: Thanks zi42 I will check Apache Soir

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to not search the text of your description column using SQL if you're concerned about working your DB too hard under high traffic, since I suspect you've got a lot of text sitting in there.  Especially since it's so far down the priority chain in your columns.

After thinking about it for a little while I am almost 100% positive that this is your biggest processing load.  I don't know how you're serving the results up in the browser but you will undoubtedly get better results with, say, python for straight up string finding.

Beyond that I'm not sure what to tell you.  You could break up your tables like you're saying, access them programmatically, and if you were to do that I'd suggest making aggregate tables.  But I really don't like that idea.

Comment: you`re rigth, this is taking me a lot of time because this is the most importat part of the project but I need to do it with php/mysql/jquery-ajax/MVC/POO..., I`ve heard a lot about python and I will definitely take a look at it someday, thanks

Comment: Well then your next best option is probably to use the Perl Regex library in PHP.